# calculate running total with a date range in where clause using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table and I want to compute the running total with a date range in where clause

```
+----------------+------------------+----------+
| Transaction ID | Transaction Date | Quantity |
+----------------+------------------+----------+
|              1 | 03-May-20        |        3 |
|              2 | 06-May-20        |        5 |
|              3 | 05-Jun-20        |       10 |
|              4 | 06-Jul-20        |        2 |
|              5 | 07-Aug-20        |        8 |
+----------------+------------------+----------+
```

Now my oracle sql query is

```
select
transaction_id,
transaction_date,
sum(quantity) over (order by transaction_date) as running_total

from table

where transaction_date >= '03-May-20' and transaction_date <= '06-Jul-20'
```

After I run the query above I got the result below

```
+----------------+------------------+----------+---------------+
| Transaction ID | Transaction Date | Quantity | Running Total |
+----------------+------------------+----------+---------------+
|              1 | 03-May-20        |        3 |            28 |
|              2 | 06-May-20        |        5 |            33 |
|              3 | 05-Jun-20        |       10 |            43 |
|              4 | 06-Jul-20        |        2 |            45 |
+----------------+------------------+----------+---------------+
```

Which is wrong because the output I want is:

```
| Transaction ID | Transaction Date | Quantity | Running Total |
+----------------+------------------+----------+---------------+
|              1 | 03-May-20        |        3 |             3 |
|              2 | 06-May-20        |        5 |             8 |
|              3 | 05-Jun-20        |       10 |            18 |
|              4 | 06-Jul-20        |        2 |            20 |
+----------------+------------------+----------+---------------+
```

Please help on what query should I used to compute the running total with a date range in where clause.

Hi, I tried to use the to_date function, but I got the same result as above (2nd table). Please see the query below,

```
select
transaction_id,
transaction_date,
sum(quantity) over (order by transaction_date) as running_total

from table

where transaction_date between TO_DATE('2019-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2020-10-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Thanks,

Comment: I don't see how your data can be producing the data that you specify.  The sum of quantity is bigger than the quantities you have shown in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Output you want (sample data in lines #1 - 7; query begins at line #8).

```
SQL> with test (transaction_id, transaction_date, quantity) as
  2    (select 1, date '2020-05-03',  3 from dual union all
  3     select 2, date '2020-05-06',  5 from dual union all
  4     select 3, date '2020-06-05', 10 from dual union all
  5     select 4, date '2020-07-06',  2 from dual union all
  6     select 5, date '2020-08-07',  8 from dual
  7    )
  8  select transaction_id,
  9    transaction_date,
 10    quantity,
 11    sum(quantity) over (order by transaction_date) running_total
 12  From test
 13  where transaction_date between date '2020-05-03' and date '2020-07-06'
 14  order by transaction_id;

TRANSACTION_ID TRANSACTIO   QUANTITY RUNNING_TOTAL
-------------- ---------- ---------- -------------
             1 03.05.2020          3             3
             2 06.05.2020          5             8
             3 05.06.2020         10            18
             4 06.07.2020          2            20

SQL>
```

Reason of your problems? I presume it is the fact that you're comparing dates to strings (`'03-May-20'` is a string, not a date). Oracle tries to implicitly convert datatypes; sometimes it succeeds, sometimes not. Your `03-May-20` might be 3rd of May 2020 or 20th of May 2003, for example.

**Always** have control over your data. Use dates when necessary, either by using `to_date` function with appropriate date format mask, or use date literal (as I did).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is "correct" but your results are not, they contain the expected Running Total but it starts from the final Total (including transaction id 5). You ran a different SQL statement.

Note that you shouldn't be storing dates as strings or comparing them to strings. That said, Oracle will be saving your bacon if your current NLS date format setting (which is very easy to change) matches your string input. You would be getting completely different results if you were ordering by a string, your results have the expected transaction date values so one would assume that this comparison has worked. You should still fix your handling of dates, but that is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Something else is going on. The data is being summed correctly in terms of dates, so the date ordering does not appear to be an issue.

The total sum is starting at the overall sum minus the first value.  So, the results look like the result of this query:

```
select transaction_id, transaction_date, quantity,
       total_quantity + sum(quantity) over (order by transaction_date)as running_total
From (select t.*,
             sum(quantity) over () - first_value(quantity) over (order by transaction_date) as total_quantity
      from test t
     ) t
where transaction_date between date '2020-05-03' and date '2020-07-06'
order by transaction_date;
```

I cannot explain why this would be happening.  It might be a bug in Oracle.  Or it might be the result of an oversimplification of your query when you asked the question.